# How to convert 3 lists into 1 3D Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three lists that I want to convert into one list. When I try the following a get this error

```
 A = numpy.array(X,Y,Z,dtype=float)
 ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted
```

I did not see anything here that says you can only give it two arguments

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

Here is the code

```
import numpy
from numpy import *

X = []
Y = []
Z = []

f = open(r'C:\My.txt')
f.readline()
for line in f:
 if line != '':
     line = line.strip()
     columns = line.split()
     x = columns[2]
     y = columns[3]
     z = columns[4]
     X.append(x)
     Y.append(y)                #appends data in list
     Z.append(z)



A = numpy.array(X,Y,Z,dtype=float)
A.shape(3,3)
print(A)
```

Thanks in advanceh

Comment: Give an example of your three lists and of your three-dimensional numpy array you want to obtain.

Comment: @eumiro right now I am using a test case where the lists are `[0,0,0,0], [3,4,4,3], [3,4,3,4]` what I would like is list one the first column list two the second list three the third. This will eventually involve three very large lists that need to be converted into one array for analysis. Thank you

Comment: You'll be getting a two-dimensional array, not three dimensional. The length of the major dimension will be three.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try passing your three lists as a tuple:

```
A = numpy.array((X, Y, Z), dtype=float)
```

In the [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) documentation the signature for `numpy.array` is

> numpy.array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0, maskna=None, ownmaskna=False)

i.e. the single argument `object` is what gets turned into an ndarray, every other argument must be a keyword argument (hence the error message which you were getting) which can be used to customise the creation of the array.

**Edit** In respone to Surfcast23's comment, in the IDE I tried the following:

```
>>> import numpy

>>> x = [0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> y = [3, 4, 4, 3]
>>> z = [3, 4, 3, 4]

>>> A = numpy.array((x, y, z), dtype=float)
>>> A
array([[ 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [ 3., 4., 4., 3.],
       [ 3., 4., 3., 4.]])
>>> A.shape
(3L, 4L)
```

Comment: Tried to give the tuple, but got a `tuple not callable error`

Comment: Then your lists aren't what you say they are or what you expect them to be. This works fine for me with your example lists given in your comment to your question (see my edit).

Comment: I just printed on of the lists and this is what I got `['0', '0', '0', '0']`. I think the quotation marks maybe the problem what do you think?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. I have just tried the above example again but with `x = ..` replaced with `x = ['0', '0', '0', '0']` and `y` and `z` replaced similiarly and I get exactly the same result for `A`. The `dtype` argument of `numpy.array` will convert strings to, in this case, floats.

Comment: @Surfcast23 - It sounds like you're doing `x.shape()`. It's not a function, it's a tuple. You can't call it.  It's just `shape = x.shape`.

Comment: @JoeKington Agreed. @Surfcast23 You can modify the shape of an array by using `A.shape = (3, 3)` rather than `A.shape(3,3)`. However, you don't need to use this at all in your code in your question. In fact, in your example you are reshaping an array to an array with a different number of elements, which would raise a `ValueError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code and found out that there is a missing [] for X,Y,Z. The array cannot take two D array as one. Try putting [X,Y,Z] for the array and you shall get the correct answer.

```
import numpy
from numpy import *

X = []
Y = []
Z = []

f = open(r'C:\My.txt')
f.readline()
for line in f:
 if line != '':
     line = line.strip()
     columns = line.split()
     x = columns[2]
     y = columns[3]
     z = columns[4]
     X.append(x)
     Y.append(y)                #appends data in list
     Z.append(z)



A = numpy.array([X,Y,Z],dtype = float)
A.shape(3,3)
print(A)
```

Comment: Never mind the fact that `import *` is bad practice, what's the point of `import numpy` followed immediately by `from numpy import *` ?